# If... else if injection with mono.cecil

Tags: c#, mono

As topic says, I'm injecting some code into the assembly. I'd like to get something like that:

```
  string str;
  int num;
  switch (choice)
  {
    case 1:
      str = "b "; num = 2; break;
    default:
      str = "a "; num = 1; break;
  }
  if(num == 1) {str += "a";}
  else if(num == 2) {str += "b";}
```

I managed to inject the switch statement and if with partial success. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
        switches[0] = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a ");
        switches[1] = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "b ");

        Instruction ifStart1 = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
        Instruction ifStart2 = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        Instruction ifEnd = worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, returnString);

        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, ""));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, returnString));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, helpInt));

        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg, choice));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Switch, switches));

        listInstr.Add(switches[0]);
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, returnString));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, helpInt));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Br, ifStart1));

        listInstr.Add(switches[1]);
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, returnString));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, helpInt));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Br, ifStart1));

        //if 1
        listInstr.Add(ifStart1);
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc,helpInt));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Bne_Un, ifEnd));

        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, returnString));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a"));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Call, concat));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, returnString));

        // if 2
        listInstr.Add(ifStart2);
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, helpInt));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Bne_Un, ifEnd));

        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldloc, returnString));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "b"));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Call, concat));
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Stloc, returnString));

        listInstr.Add(ifEnd);
        listInstr.Add(worker.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
```

Unfortunately it generates nested ifs in the decompiler. I tried adding the opcode Ret instruction (as I saw on some sites) but it confuses decompiler and it can't generate code. I don't know which opcodes I should use or how the instructions should be made for the if statement to work as an example I gave before. Is there a way I could improve my code?

Comment: Go for it. What's stopping you? When you ask a question, you should probably include a question somewhere in your post.

Comment: What's your question? "How to do that" is too broad. What attempts have you made?

Comment: I'm sorry, by accident I posted the question before I ended it. It's full now.